# How to show relevant data through SQL View

Tags: sql, sql-view

I made a view in SQL Management Studio and it is working fine but there is a problem when I search data by specific ID it shows more than one rows of the data.
Note: View is getting data from two tables and these tables contain one same ID column, Name of the same Column is "Reservation ID"
I have attached a picture of the scenario. Please guide me where i am making mistake.
[image: Scenerio of the problem]

Thanks

```
select Reservation.Reservation_ID
      ,Reservation.Customer_ID
      ,Reservati‌​on.Exact_Arrival
      ,Res‌​ervation.Exact_Depar‌​ture,Reservation.Num‌​ber_of_Persons
      ,Reser‌​vation.Room_Floor
      ,Re‌​servation.Room_Numbe‌​r
      ,Reservation.Room_T‌​ype
      ,Reservation.Vehi‌​cle_Number
      ,Customers‌​Details.Customer_Add‌​ress
      ,CustomersDetail‌​s.Customer_CNIC
      ,Cust‌​omersDetails.Custome‌​r_Full_Name
      ,Customer‌​sDetails.Customer_Ph‌​one_Number 
from Reservation,CustomersDetails;
```

Comment: can show the query for the view?

Comment: Sure I did not save it but I can rewrite it.

Comment: You can right click on your view in "SQL Management Studio" and then click on design. That should give you the code that created it.

Comment: @RajatMishra Here it is  create view [dbo].[V_Information] As select Reservation.Reservation_ID,Reservation.Customer_ID,Reservation.Exact_Arrival,Reservation.Exact_Departure,Reservation.Number_of_Persons,Reservation.Room_Floor,Reservation.Room_Number,Reservation.Room_Type,Reservation.Vehicle_Number,CustomersDetails.Customer_Address,CustomersDetails.Customer_CNIC,CustomersDetails.Customer_Full_Name,CustomersDetails.Customer_Phone_Number from Reservation,CustomersDetails;

Comment: Guessing your CustomerDetails table has more than one address per customer? You're going to get a row for each one. Also would recommend using the `JOIN` syntax as the comma joins are 25+ years outdated.

Comment: Agree with Jacob; you are simply pulling back everything from both tables. if reservations has 1 row, and customerDetails has 2 rows (which it looks like in this case), its going to duplicate that reservation row two times to match the second table.

Comment: @JJWillMC Both Tables has two rows. should I update the view and put "where" clause at the end?  like this where "Reservation_ID>=1". The first row contains the data of "Reservation_ID" In both table other fields are NULL.

Comment: Is there a relationship between these two tables? if there is why not do a join on them as @JacobH suggested? I would assume both tables had a "Customer_ID" field. Why not join on that with your view? That will give your view an actual purpose then of joining the two tables into one big table of information. The way you have it currently, the view is basically meaningless since you just dump all the data into it.

Comment: @JJWillMC Yes They both have two same fields, Customer_ID, Reservation_ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments you and I had, it appears that you need to build your view  a little bit differently. You currently are dumping all the information back from both tables with no joins in place.
Build you view as so,

```
create view [dbo].[V_Information] 
As select Reservation.Reservation_ID,
Reservation.Customer_ID,
Reservati‌​on.Exact_Arrival,
Res‌​ervation.Exact_Depar‌​ture,
Reservation.Num‌​ber_of_Persons,
Reser‌​vation.Room_Floor,
Re‌​servation.Room_Numbe‌​r,
Reservation.Room_T‌​ype,
Reservation.Vehi‌​cle_Number,
Customers‌​Details.Customer_Add‌​ress,
CustomersDetail‌​s.Customer_CNIC,
Cust‌​omersDetails.Custome‌​r_Full_Name,
Customer‌​sDetails.Customer_Ph‌​one_Number 
from 
Reservation
INNER JOIN CustomersDetails
    ON Reservations.Customer_ID = CustomerDetails.Customer_ID;
```

Comment: The original query has a cross join. It is one of the reasons why it is a very bad technique to use implicit joins. You get accidental cross joins. It is irresponsible not to learn how to correctly write joins. If you don't understand what you are doing, you have a huge chance of getting incorrect results. The fact that query runs is not enough, you have to know what the data means.